# Debuging lua application using ZeroBraneStudio with own lua interpreter

Tags: lua, zerobrane

I would like to debug my application using ZeroBraneStudio 1.4 with my own lua interpreter (5.1) on Windows 7.

I set the interpreter in `user.lua` as

```
path.lua = '<PATH_OWN_INTERPRETER>'
```

`my_app.lua` has the following as the first line

```
package.path = package.path .. ';../CommonScripts/?.lua'
print(package.path)
```

which prints

```
;.\?.lua;<PATH_OWN_INTERPRETER>\lua\?.lua;<PATH_OWN_INTERPRETER>\lua\?\init.lua;<PATH_OWN_INTERPRETER>\?.lua;<PATH_OWN_INTERPRETER>\?\init.lua;./?.lua;./?/init.lua;./lua/?.lua;./lua/?/init.lua;<PATH_ZBS>\lualibs/?/?.lua;<PATH_ZBS>\lualibs/?.lua;<PATH_ZBS>\lualibs/?/?/init.lua;<PATH_ZBS>\lualibs/?/init.lua;../CommonScripts/?.lua
```

When I start debugging, the following error occurs.

```
<PATH_ZBS>\lualibs/ssl.lua:19: module 'ssl.x509' not found:
    no field package.preload['ssl.x509']
    no file '.\ssl\x509.lua'
    no file '<PATH_OWN_INTERPRETER>\lua\ssl\x509.lua'
    no file '<PATH_OWN_INTERPRETER>\lua\ssl\x509\init.lua'
    no file '<PATH_OWN_INTERPRETER>\ssl\x509.lua'
    no file '<PATH_OWN_INTERPRETER>\ssl\x509\init.lua'
    no file './ssl\x509.lua'
    no file './ssl\x509/init.lua'
    no file './lua/ssl\x509.lua'
    no file './lua/ssl\x509/init.lua'
    no file '<PATH_ZBS>\lualibs/ssl\x509/ssl\x509.lua'
    no file '<PATH_ZBS>\lualibs/ssl\x509.lua'
    no file '<PATH_ZBS>\lualibs/ssl\x509/ssl\x509/init.lua'
    no file '<PATH_ZBS>\lualibs/ssl\x509/init.lua'
    no file '../CommonScripts/ssl\x509.lua'
    no file '.\ssl\x509.dll'
    no file '.\ssl\x50951.dll'
    no file '<PATH_OWN_INTERPRETER>\ssl\x509.dll'
    no file '<PATH_OWN_INTERPRETER>\ssl\x50951.dll'
    no file '<PATH_OWN_INTERPRETER>\clibs\ssl\x509.dll'
    no file '<PATH_OWN_INTERPRETER>\clibs\ssl\x50951.dll'
    no file '<PATH_OWN_INTERPRETER>\loadall.dll'
    no file '<PATH_OWN_INTERPRETER>\clibs\loadall.dll'
    no file '<PATH_ZBS>\bin/ssl\x509.dll'
    no file '<PATH_ZBS>\bin/clibs/ssl\x509.dll'
    no module 'ssl.x509' in file '<PATH_OWN_INTERPRETER>\ssl.dll'
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'require'
    <PATH_ZBS>\lualibs/ssl.lua:19: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'require'
    <PATH_OWN_INTERPRETER>\ssl\https.lua:10: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'require'
    ../CommonScripts/Class2.lua:36: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'require'
    ../CommonScripts/Class1.lua:40: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'require'
    my_app.lua:48: in main chunk
```

I have the following line in `Class2.lua:36`

```
local https = require'ssl.https'
```

It seems that the ZBS is mixing up the directories of built in Lua interpreter with the one that I would like to use.

How can I prevent this?

Comment: Probably, this is because you don't have `<PATH_OWN_INTERPRETER>\ssl.lua`, so it was found in `ZBS` path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently when the lua path in `user.lua` is set as

```
path.lua = '<PATH_OWN_INTERPRETER>'
```

It is expanded by ZeroBrane Studio to

```
<PATH_OWN_INTERPRETER>\lua\?.lua;
<PATH_OWN_INTERPRETER>\lua\?\init.lua;
<PATH_OWN_INTERPRETER>\?.lua;
<PATH_OWN_INTERPRETER>\?\init.lua;
```

In my own interpreter, ssl is located at `<PATH_OWN_INTERPRETER>\lua\ssl\ssl.lua` with is not included in the list above.

So, my solution was to define `LUA_PATH` as environmental variables so that I get

```
<PATH_OWN_INTERPRETER>/?.lua;
<PATH_OWN_INTERPRETER>/lua/?.lua;
<PATH_OWN_INTERPRETER>/lua/?/?.lua;
```

in the path.

Answer (score 0):

@EgorSkriptunoff is correct in his comment: You have `<PATH_OWN_INTERPRETER>\ssl.dll`, which doesn't seem to have `ssl.x509` module (`no module 'ssl.x509' in file '<PATH_OWN_INTERPRETER>\ssl.dll'`) and don't have `<PATH_OWN_INTERPRETER>\ssl.lua`, so the Lua version of the module is loaded from ZeroBrane Studio folders, but the binary part of the module is loaded from your Lua folders and is missing  (for some reason x509 component). You need to use both (Lua and binary) components from the same source.